# How to process GET request in Django CMS forms?

Tags: django, forms, content-management-system, django-cms

I am new to Django CMS.  Previously, I had built a simple Django project with an HTML form sending a GET request.

The user would input something and the code in `views.py` would determine what page to GET or display.

```
<form action="/search/" method="get" name="f1">
    ...
    //user selects A, B, or C here
    ...
</form>
```

And in the `views.py`, something like:

```
def search(request):
    if A:
        variable = "A"
        return render(request, "A.html", {"Option A": variable})
    if B:
        variable = "B"
        return render(request, "B.html", {"Option B": variable})
    if C:
        variable = "C"
        return render(request, "C.html", {"Option C": variable})
```

Now that I have Django CMS, I am lost on how to reconstruct this logic again. I've already created a page that displays the HTML form.  Now, do I create pages for each A.html, B.html and C.html in CMS?  If so, where do I place the logic that determines when each page gets displayed and a variable that needs to be passed in from the controller to the template?

In case it helps, my `urls.py` is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a feature called [apphooks](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/extending_cms/app_integration.html#app-hooks).

Basically they allow you to take over the rendering of a page and provide your own view thus allowing you to render the page yourself.

Apphooks work like plugins in the way that you need to register them in order for the cms to pick them up, so create a file called `cms_app.py` and in this file you then create your apphook, like so:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool


class ProductsApphook(CMSApp):
    name = _("Products app")
    urls = [
        patterns('myapp.views',
            url(
                r'^$',
                'product_list',
                name="product_listing"
            ),
            url(
                r'^product/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',
                'product_detail_view',
                name="product_detail"
            ),
        )

    ]

apphook_pool.register(ProductsApphook)
```

As you can see, apphooks are very simple. They take a name and then a url mapping, mind you that here I provided the url patterns in the apphook definition but if there were more urls then you can place there urls in your `urls.py` and then point to it from your apphook, like so `urls = ['myapp.urls']`

So say our page is called `products` and you can access it from `/en/products`, when you go to `/en/products/` , this will trigger the product_list view and when you go to `/products/product/10` this will trigger view `product_detail_view` with `pk = 10`.

Once your view is called, then you can just easily reuse your view above.

[Here's](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-search/blob/master/aldryn_search/cms_app.py) an example of an apphook being used for search.